# jQuery is not defined in Chrome's javascript console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a simple jQuery function to click on the "following" buttons of Medium. I wrote this but it returns **"Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"**

```
__cnt__ = 0;
jQuery('.button-activeState').each(function(i, ele) {
    ele = jQuery(ele);
    if (ele.css('display') != 'inline') {
        //alert('already following:', i);
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        ele.click();
    }, __cnt__++ * 500);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `jQuery` included ? Is this script executing before `jquery` is included ?

Answer (score 4):

To include jQuery 2.1.4, you could run the following in the console:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 0):

> **"Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"**

Mean that there's no jquery included, so make sure that jquery is included, and place your script after include of librairy.