# Chrome extension to load the script without clicking on icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hello all i want to load the script whether or not user clicks on my extension icon
This is my extension it works great but i want it to work without making the user click on the icon to load the scripts ..

Here is the code .

```
  {
   "name": "Injecta",
    "version": "0.0.1",
     "manifest_version": 2,
      "description": "Injecting stuff",

        "background":
         {
         "scripts": ["jquery.js","background.js"]
              },
            "browser_action": {
             "default_title": "Inject!"
              },
              "permissions": [
              "https://*/*",
               "http://*/*",
                "tabs"
                  ]
                  }
```

This is my background.js

```
     chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      file: 'jquery.js'
           });
         chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            file: 'inject.js'
             });
                });
```

i just want the extension to load all the scripts with the page load. currently user has to click on the icon to load the scripts..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484726/jquery-is-not-defined-in-chromes-javascript-console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `executeScript` does is basically creating a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) dynamically. This is called [Programmatic Injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi).

An alternative method of working with content scripts is [specifying them in the manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration). This achieves exactly what you're asking: content scripts are executed automatically when the page is loaded.

```
"content_scripts" : [
   {
     "js": ["jquery.js", "inject.js"],
     "matches": ["*://*/*"]
   }
],
```

Adjust the `matches` parameter to only include [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) for pages you want it to run on.

Make sure to check out the documentation of `run_at` parameter if you need to fine-tune when injection happens.

Comment: Possibly, but that should be a new question. It also seems like a pretty basic question - make sure you [do your research first](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2):

`if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {}`