# Chrome extension Javascript running only on icon click

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want my Chrome Extension to load Javascript once user visits a website. But currently, the Javascript is executed only when user click the extension icon and till the extension popup is open.

I saw the answer in this [Chrome extension to load the script without clicking on icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468774/chrome-extension-to-load-the-script-without-clicking-on-icon) question.

My manifest.json is:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Javascript example",
  "description": "Some description.",
  "version": "1.1",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["popup.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The popup.js is:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  alert("Working");
});
```

popup.html is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

The alert dialog is shown only when I click the extension icon (i.e. when popup.html is run), not when a page loads. I want the popup.js file to execute without user needing to click the extension icon. What am I missing?

Comment: Add `"run_at":"document_start"` in the `content_scripts` entry in the manifest.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko Worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your manifest works, but `run_at` defaults to `document_idle` which means that `DOMContentLoaded` has already fired. This can be fixed by specifying `run_at` to `document_start` instead.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Javascript example",
  "description": "Some description.",
  "version": "1.1",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["popup.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Answer (score 1):

You need the content script.

> Content scripts are JavaScript files that run in the context of web
>   pages. By using the standard Document Object Model (DOM), they can
>   read details of the web pages the browser visits, or make changes to
>   them.
>
> Here are some examples of what content scripts can do:
>
> - Find unlinked URLs in web pages and convert them into hyperlinks
> - Increase the font size to make text more legible
> - Find and process microformat data in the DOM

If your content script's code should always be injected, register it in the extension manifest using the content_scripts field, as in the following example.

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Refer [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) link for more information & implementation.

Comment: But I already have content_scripts written in manifest.json. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you update the question with your files' content?

Comment: Updated the question with contents of popup.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use content script that runs in the context of the page and this way you'll know when the user visits a specific site: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: Please can you elaborate with example

Comment: there's an example at the link provided in the answer? did you want your manifest rewritten for you?

Comment: I have written the mainfest.json with content scripts. I'm asking what's wrong in what I've written