# Chrome extension start working without clicking on icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468774/chrome-extension-to-load-the-script-without-clicking-on-icon), but do not help me, so I want my extension start working without clicking the icon?

**manifest.js**

```
"name":"test",
    "description":"test.",
    "version":"1.1.1",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "icons": { 
        "16": "icons/icon16.png",
        "48": "icons/icon48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon128.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/icon128.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
        },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
        },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "js": ["jquery.js","content.js"],
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "run_at": "document_end",
          "all_frames": true    
        }
        ],
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>",
        "storage", 
        "activeTab"
       ]
```

**background.js**

```
    ! function(t) {
    var e = {};

    function n(o) {
        if (e[o]) return e[o].exports;
        var r = e[o] = {
            i: o,
            l: !1,
            exports: {}
        };
        return t[o].call(r.exports, r, r.exports, n), r.l = !0, r.exports
    }
    n.m = t, n.c = e, n.d = function(t, e, o) {
        n.o(t, e) || Object.defineProperty(t, e, {
            configurable: !1,
            enumerable: !0,
            get: o
        })
    }, n.n = function(t) {
        var e = t && t.__esModule ? function() {
            return t.default
        } : function() {
            return t
        };
        return n.d(e, "a", e), e
    }, n.o = function(t, e) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t, e)
    }, n.p = "", n(n.s = 0)
}([function(t, e) {
    chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL("https:// website /contact/");
    const n = t => (t => {
        const e = Object.keys(t).filter(e => t[e]).map(e => e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(t[e])).join("&");
        fetch("https://www.google-analytics.com/collect", {
            method: "POST",
            body: e
        }).then(() => {}).catch(() => {})
    })(Object.assign({
        v: 1,
        tid: "UA-000000-5",
        cid: (() => {
            const t = localStorage.getItem("cid");
            return t || (rndCid = Math.round(1e15 * Math.random()).toString(32), localStorage.setItem("cid", rndCid), rndCid)
        })(),
        t: "pageview"
    }, t));
    n(), window.trackEvent = ((t = "unknown", e = "unknown", o) => {
        (({
            category: t,
            action: e,
            label: o
        }) => n({
            t: "event",
            ec: t,
            ea: e,
            el: o
        }))({
            category: t,
            action: e,
            label: o
        })
    }), chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(t => {
        !0 === t.__ga && window.trackEvent(t.category, t.action, t.label)
    })
}]);
```

I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468774/chrome-extension-to-load-the-script-without-clicking-on-icon), but do not help me, so I want my extension start working without clicking the icon?

**is possible extension start without clicking the icon, that's what I'm trying to do today, so I have all day and still, I don't have fix this problem, so please help me. Thanks**

Comment: 1. No such thing as `document.ready`, you meant [jQuery's ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), 2. move jquery.js up so it's the first `<script>`, 3. start using the proper devtools - right-click the popup, click "Inspect", 4. don't load script.js as a content script because it runs in the web page which is a totally different page, not related to the popup.

Comment: Thanks for your help, my question was wrong, I just modified the question, so please review my question once again! Thank you very mouch.